# How to prevent content click to toggle parent in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm making a title click to toggle content....

What I want is once the content is shown...prevent from toggle it if click it on the yellow area. (Im using `li` and I want it to remain like that)

```js
$(".liContent").hide();
$(document).on("click","li",function() { 

$(this).find(".liContent").toggle();


});
```

```css
li{margin:5px; border:1px solid red}
.liContent{background:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>A <div class="liContent">A Content</div>
</li>

<li>B <div class="liContent">B Content</div>
</li>

</ul>
```

**How can I do it?**

Comment: `.toggle()` is used specifically to flip between `show` and  `hide`. If you only want it to show, then just use `.show()`.

Comment: Do you mean, when `.liContent` is visible, then if I click on it, it shouldn't hide?

Comment: I want to toggle it like wikipedia in mobile version

Comment: Calvin, prevent to toggle if clicking on `A content` or `B content`...in other workds if clicking on the yellow area

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding an event argument to your function (`e`), you could target the clicked item using `e.target`. It differs from `$(this)`, which refers to the element to which the handler is bound (or, in the case of your event delegation, the delegated element `li`).

To make sure the clicked element is **not** `liContent`, you can use `!$(e.target).is(".liContent")`:

```
if (!$(e.target).is(".liContent")) {
  //.liContent was not clicked
}
```

```js
$(".liContent").hide();
$(document).on("click", "li", function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).is(".liContent")) {
    $(this).find(".liContent").toggle();
  }
});
```

```css
li {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red
}

.liContent {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>A
    <div class="liContent">A Content</div>
  </li>
  <li>B
    <div class="liContent">B Content</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to hide it after it was shown. You could just use the `show()` function instead of `toggle()`;

I think it's a simple and quick approach to it.

```js
$(".liContent").hide();
$(document).on("click","li",function() { 

    $(this).find(".liContent").show();

});
```

```css
li{margin:5px; border:1px solid red}
.liContent{background:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>A <div class="liContent">A Content</div>
</li>

<li>B <div class="liContent">B Content</div>
</li>

</ul>
```